# Why my competition results are disappearing from my profile page at Kaggle?

Tags: kaggle

I've participated in 3 competitions at Kaggle (one was already ended) but only 1 of them can be seen in my profile page at Kaggle now. Recently, my Titanic competition result has disappeared. Does anybody know what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The leaderboards for the getting started competitions (Titanic, Housing Prices Regression and Digit Recognizer) are cleared on a rolling basis. That way if you're just entering to try it out it doesn't clutter your profile forever. The leaderboards from other competitions aren't cleared.